# How can I change the font in this project?

Tags: fonts

I have just a general knowledge on LaTeX. Generally I am able to edit some features of the projects on overleaf. However, in the one below, I could not find how to change the font of the body text.

the link of the project : https://tr.overleaf.com/latex/templates/awesome-cv/dfnvtnhzhhbm

the text section I want to change the font of is the text in the image below

[image]

I want to change the font of the gray text, not the "Summary" part.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The fonts are included into a folder of the author Claud D. Park named `\fontdir[fonts/]`.

Comment: @Sebastiano the problem is I could not find where exactly I should modify

Comment: There is also a license: `% Template license:
% CC BY-SA 4.0 (https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)
%` and the colors, for the text, are defined by the code (HTML): `% Colors for text
% Uncomment if you would like to specify your own color
% \definecolor{darktext}{HTML}{414141}
% \definecolor{text}{HTML}{333333}
% \definecolor{graytext}{HTML}{5D5D5D}
% \definecolor{lighttext}{HTML}{999999}`

Comment: Please clarify your objective: Are you asking how to switch from a serif to a sans-serif font, or are you asking how to set up a *specific* sans-serif font? It it's the latter, do you know the name of said sans-serif font?

Comment: @Mico actually I don't have that much knowledge on fonts. All I want to do is, being able to set let's say font Arial instead of the font which is currently being used. I was thinking the modification should be done on the part where Boris mentioned in his answer. But I am not able to do it.

Answer (score 4):

The original class contains the lines

```
\newcommand*{\footerfont}{\sourcesanspro}
\newcommand*{\bodyfont}{\sourcesanspro}
\newcommand*{\bodyfontlight}{\sourcesansprolight}
```

So if you do, for example, add to your document

```
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\renewcommand{\footerfont}{\fontfamily{ppl}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\bodyfont}{\fontfamily{ppl}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\bodyfontlight}{\fontfamily{ppl}\selectfont}
```

you will switch to Palatino in your document

Comment: So I was on the right track, however, copying those 4 lines you provided below the three lines above; did not result in a successfull output. It added "ppl" in front of each line. It compiled the pdf, but gave also errors.

Comment: The command name is `\fontfamily` not `\family` - and depending on the use there is perhaps also a `\selectfont` missing.

Comment: Thanks - updated!

Comment: Very good for my humble opinion. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: thank you for this. I'm using the same template, and (frankly) the Awesome Fonts as well as the SourceSansPro fonts look like garbage for me. I'd much rather be able to specify them myself.